# How to update JSF 2.2 to JSF 2.3 using Maven in a Spring Application

Tags: spring, maven, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using `MAVEN` and already changed my `pom.xml` dependencies from:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

to:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but now I get a build error:

> javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
>           at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.tryAddCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:312) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:242) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:484) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.performOneTimeELInitialization(ApplicationImpl.java:1404) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:526) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:256) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
>
> 2017-05-15 11:12:44.071 ERROR 9936 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
>           at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:315) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
>   Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
>           at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.tryAddCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:312) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:242) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:484) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.performOneTimeELInitialization(ApplicationImpl.java:1404) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:526) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
>           at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:256) ~[javax.faces-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]

I also updated the version in my `faces-config.xml` to 2.3:

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
          version="2.3">
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    <el-resolver>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

Are there more changes to make in the `pom.xml` or anywhere else in my application?

Comment: You question title 'How to update...' is way to broad for the problem. Please improve the title... And a full stacktrace most likely contains the reason... I only see Spring errors here, nothing JSF related

Comment: thx for your advice @Kukeltje .. I updated the question

Comment: I guess in faces-config.xml the xsi:schemaLocation should also be updated to 2.3: http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd

Answer (score 11):

Old question, but for people still facing this problem: To avoid the "Unable to find CDI BeanManager" error, it's important that your `faces-config.xml` version is **not** `2.3` and your `web.xml` version is **not** `4.0`!

The Mojarra implementation [ELUtils class](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/el/ELUtils.java) contains the following nice bit of code:

```
if (getFacesConfigXmlVersion(facesContext).equals("2.3") || getWebXmlVersion(facesContext).equals("4.0")) {
                throw new FacesException("Unable to find CDI BeanManager");
}
```

When using lower versions, it skips this check, and works with Spring DI instead of CDI.

Comment: I can't understand why this nice little piece of code is inside GlassFish's JSF implementation! The jar is versioned 2.3 yet it throws an exception if used under Servlet 4.0? Or I wrongly understood this?

Comment: IF you are using `@ManagedBean` annotations this is needed. If you are using `@Named` (as you should) you don't get this error

Answer (score 1):

1. Add CDI and weld dependency `pom.xml`

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
       <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.9.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. create `beans.xml` in `WEB-INF`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://jboss.org/schema/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd
       http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans_1_1.xsd">

     <weld:scan>
       <weld:exclude name="org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.**" />
       <weld:exclude name="com.example.beans.**" />
     </weld:scan>
   </beans>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my answear may appears unrelated to this question, but it is...
I experienced exactly this exception, and it was not the first time. I have one enviroment in production and another, for development. They are identical, as much as possible. My environment is glassfish 4.1.2, updated to use mojarra 2.3 (I've swapped the glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.faces.jar file). I have some secure certificates in one .jks file, and this information is very important, one jvm setting called "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", with default value "changeit". For some strange reason this setting disappeared in one deploy. I don't know why, but it happened. My conclusion is that this missing setting had thrown one exception BEFORE the exception "javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager" and I could not diagnose it. That was the only differece between this two environments. So, if your application is throwing this exception and it uses some .jks file, just verify that this setting is not missing in your jvm settings.